# Struts - Uploading Files

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, struts

I'm having a problem uploading a file using spring webflow 1.0 and struts 1.3.

The jsp is something like this:

```
<html:form action="/flowAction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- snip -->
    <html:file property="file" name="attachDocumentsForm" size="50"/>
    <!-- snip -->
</html:form>
```

The Form is something like this:

```
public class AttachDocumentsForm extends SpringBindingActionForm {
    // note, SpringBindingActionForm extends struts' ActionForm
    private FormFile file;
    //snip
}
```

Now, my problem is that when I submit the form, the `file` field is always `null`.   The other fields on the form are filled out properly, and if I dig through the `RequestContext`, I can find the file is buried deep some of the data structures there.

Here is the **horribly** ugly way that I can get at the attachment:

```
// 'context' is the RequestContext
ServletExternalContext servletExternalContext = (ServletExternalContext) context.getExternalContext();
ActionForm form = (ActionForm) servletExternalContext.getRequest().getAttribute("actionForm");
FormFile file = (FormFile) form.getMultipartRequestHandler().getFileElements().get("file");
```

I've noticed that the `MultipartRequestHandler` on my form is `null`, and I suspect that this might be part of the problem, but I've tried populating it with an instance of `CommonsMultipartRequestHandler` to no avail.

What do I need to do to let the `file` field be populated correctly?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to get the file from the ActionForm accessor, using (FormFile) form.getFile()?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should configure spring dispatcher servlet: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-multipart-resolver

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will look into this.   I know that I consulted the docs you linked, and defined a multipart resolver as part of that process.  I am not at all sure that I had it wired up correctly though (it's been a few months since I looked at this).   I'll take another pass at it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field called file of type `FormFile` in your `ActionForm` (the one referred by `attachDocumentsForm`), along with the accessor methods.

The uploaded file can be accessed by calling `form.getFile()`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but that's just the problem.    I already have one of those fields on the ActionForm, but it is always null.

Comment: I don't know if anyone came through this since 2006, but I have the exact same problem in a legacy project I'm working on... if someone has the solution, that'd be great :-)